# Set Dynamic height for row of Master tableview, which is having another slave tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I want to dynamically set the height of row for the master table-view according to the height of inner slave table-view. Which is the best way to achieve that?
[image]

Comment: Trying to put a tableview inside a cell of a tableview is generally not a great idea, because tableviews are designed for scrolling. That said, you certainly *can* do it, you just have to fix the height of the "inner" table. Options are: using a custom view; using a Stack view in your cell instead of a tableview; using multiple Sections in your table; probably a couple other ways, depending on what all you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a default height constraint for inner table-view and set the bottom constraint priority low. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to set row height of outer tableview dynamically.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**OR**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

With the above code the row height of outer tableview will set dynamically as per the height of inner tableview.

Comment: inner tableview must have fixed or minimum height and constraints should also satisfy height increase of the row, i.e bottom of inner table constraint should have relation(= or >= or <=) with bottom of row

Comment: Yup, That's how I did. Set a default height constraint for inner table-view and set the bottom constraint priority low. Now it's working. Thanks for the response mate.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.